# Getting a memory map using BIOS interrupt 0x15 Function 0xE820

Tags: memory

I've seen [this](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev17.html) tutorial about memory and I have a question. I noticed that the code that gets a map of memory using BIOS INT 0x15 Function 0xE820 checks to see whether or not the list is one entry long. I was wondering why the list should be one entry long. I understand that some BIOSs don't support this interrupt, but isn't it enough to check if EAX = SMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed this question to Benjamin David Lunt and he replied:

> There has been a lot of discussion in the past on alt.os.development 
>   about this exact subject.
>
> Even some tests have been performed to see if that test is sufficient.
>
> Come to find out, there are some bugs in some BIOS' that you cannot 
>   rely on that test.
>
> Lately, most BIOS manufactures write code that will work for Windows 
>   or Linux and its variations. If it works for those platforms, they 
>   don't do anymore tests. If Windows, for example, only checks EBX  for
>   zero, then they don't even bother making EAX = SMAP.
>
> Therefore, you should test for all conditions so that it works on  all
>   BIOS'.